# tSQL Remote Debugging via SSMS not working even if firewalls are disabled

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, remote-debugging

I am trying to do remote debugging on DB servers but I am getting

[image: Error screen shot]

Please note that I am getting this error even though firewall is off at both sides i.e. DB server and client machine.

I have googled around and see solutions around adding firewall rules and exceptions. I don't think that should be applicable if firewall is off.

Still, I have taken steps defined at this [image: MS Docs link] but no luck.